# Is the Lubuntu recommended email software Trojita, Sylpheed, or something else?

Tags: lubuntu, software-recommendation, email, documentation, sylpheed

My Lubuntu setup, upgraded today from 16 to [18.04.1 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.42245733.1312187751.1539976999-799175861.1539976999), has Sylpheed 3.5.1, but [the Lubuntu Manual says trojita is the default](https://manual.lubuntu.me/2/2.1/2.1.5/trojita.html).

I have noticed the Sylpheed documentation is missing graphics, which makes me think developer support is lacking. However, I do not see Trojita listed in the Lubuntu Software Center searching 'mail' in the 'Internet' category! Is it only for 18.10?

Should I switch to trojita? Why does the Lubuntu Manual say trojita is the default? Why was this decision made to switch?

Answer (score 0):

The Lubuntu Manual is designed for 18.10 installs, and not much documentation is focused towards the LTS releases.

The manual in general is a work in progress, but [I created a task for it](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T112) in our Phabricator instance.

Thanks!